# Writing version info to a file using Makefile

Tags: makefile, version, gnu-make

I am writing FW version to a file and then reading it while build I my project via Makefile. The `SET` rule writes the FW version info to the file and `GET` reads it from it.

When I do

```
make SET FW_VERSION_MAJOR=1 FW_VERSION_MINOR=2 FW_VERSION_PATCH=3 FW_VERSION_REVISION=4
make GET returns 1.2.3.4
```

But when I just do

```
make SET FW_VERSION_MAJOR=1
```

`make GET` returns `1...`

What I want to achieve is if some one wants to do `make SET` and want to change only 1 or 2 or 3 parameters out of 4 in the FW version info then my `version.h` file should be able to retrieve the info left and shouldn't updated with an empty field.

```
FILE_CONFIG := path/to/version.h

.PHONY: SET GET

SET: VER_MAJOR ?= $(FW_VERSION_MAJOR)
SET: VER_MINOR ?= $(FW_VERSION_MINOR)
SET: VER_PATCH ?= $(FW_VERSION_PATCH)
SET: VER_REVISION ?= $(FW_VERSION_REVISION)
SET:
        @echo '#define FW_VERSION_MAJOR $(FW_VERSION_MAJOR)\r\n#define 
FW_VERSION_MINOR $(FW_VERSION_MINOR)\r\n#define FW_VERSION_PATCH 
$(FW_VERSION_PATCH)\r\n#define FW_VERSION_REVISION $(FW_VERSION_REVISION)' 
> $(FILE_CONFIG)

GET:

getnum = $(shell sed -n 's/.*$1  *\([0-9*]\)/\1/p' $(FILE_CONFIG))
FW_VERSION := $(call getnum,MAJOR).$(call getnum,MINOR).$(call 
getnum,PATCH).$(call getnum,REVISION)
```

Comment: Does the order of the definitions in the file matter?

Comment: Your `GET` rule is empty, please show what it looks like. Moreover, your version numbers cannot be letters. Use digits in your example.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet I think he erroneously  inserted line breaks, the following line should be the recipe, also in the `SET` rule.

Comment: @Vroomfondel I don't think so. The result would be to have make constructs in a shell recipe.

Comment: I wonder what exactly you are trying to achieve. Setting version numbers this way isn't really safe or comfortable, nor does it fit into an automated configuration process. Maybe you want to program your software build with something more capable than pure make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I fully understand what you try to achieve but there are several things to fix in your Makefile and examples:

1. your `SET`-specific variable definitions (`VER_MAJOR`...) are useless
2. your `GET` rule is empty
3. your example uses letters-only version numbers while your `getnum` macro retrieves digits-only version numbers
4. you must define the `FW_VERSION_XXX` if you want to use them in a rule when they are not passed on the command line

Try this, maybe:

```
FILE_CONFIG := version.h

.PHONY: SET GET

SET:
    @echo '#define FW_VERSION_MAJOR $(FW_VERSION_MAJOR)\r\n#define FW_VERSION_MINOR $(FW_VERSION_MINOR)\r\n#define FW_VERSION_PATCH $(FW_VERSION_PATCH)\r\n#define FW_VERSION_REVISION $(FW_VERSION_REVISION)' > $(FILE_CONFIG)

GET:
    @printf '%s\r\n' '$(FW_VERSION)'

getnum = $(shell sed -n 's/.*$1  *\([0-9*]\)/\1/p' $(FILE_CONFIG))
FW_VERSION_MAJOR := $(call getnum,MAJOR)
FW_VERSION_MINOR := $(call getnum,MINOR)
FW_VERSION_PATCH := $(call getnum,PATCH)
FW_VERSION_REVISION := $(call getnum,REVISION)
FW_VERSION := $(FW_VERSION_MAJOR).$(FW_VERSION_MINOR).$(FW_VERSION_PATCH).$(FW_VERSION_REVISION)
```

Demo:

```
$ make SET FW_VERSION_MAJOR=1 FW_VERSION_MINOR=2 FW_VERSION_PATCH=3 FW_VERSION_REVISION=4
$ make GET
1.2.3.4
$ make SET FW_VERSION_REVISION=5
$ make GET
1.2.3.5
```

Note: we can factorize a bit the `FW_VERSION_XXX` definitions and also the `SET` recipe:

```
FILE_CONFIG := version.h
VERSIONS    := MAJOR MINOR PATCH REVISION

.PHONY: SET GET

SET:
    @printf '' > $(FILE_CONFIG)
    @$(foreach v,$(VERSIONS),$(call setnum,$(v)))

GET:
    @printf '%s\r\n' '$(FW_VERSION)'

setnum = printf '\#define FW_VERSION_$1 $(FW_VERSION_$1)\r\n' >> $(FILE_CONFIG);
getnum = $(shell sed -n 's/.*$1  *\([0-9*]\)/\1/p' $(FILE_CONFIG))
$(foreach v,$(VERSIONS),$(eval FW_VERSION_$(v) := $(call getnum,$(v))))
FW_VERSION := $(FW_VERSION_MAJOR).$(FW_VERSION_MINOR).$(FW_VERSION_PATCH).$(FW_VERSION_REVISION)
```